# Triggering Flash message from stimulus controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs

I’m trying to implement share functionality with rails7, stimulus and [navigator.share](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share), which is not supported in every browser. For those cases, I need to copy a link to a clipboard but show a flash message. I have a problem with the flash message. What is the correct approach to solving this problem, and is it even possible to do so?

**Share button**

```
<div data-controller="share" 
     data-share-target="trigger" 
     data-share-url-value="<%= post_url(@post) %>"  
     data-share-name-value="<%= @post.name %>">
  <%= button_to "", data: { action: "click->share#share" } do %>
    <%= inline_svg_tag "svg/share.svg", class: 'h-6 w-6' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Stimulus controller**

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["trigger"];
  static values = ["name"];

  connect() {}

  async share(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const shareData = {
      name: this.nameValue,
      url: this.data.get("urlValue"),
      text: "some cool text",
      title: "title here",
    };

    try {
      if (navigator.share) {
        await navigator.share(shareData);
      } else {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.data.get("urlValue"));

        // Trigger Flash message here
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}
```

**My flash**

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<body class="min-h-full flex flex-col h-full">
    <main class="flex-1">
      <div id="flash" class="w-full">
        <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
          <div>
            <p><%= value %></p>
          </div>
          <% end %>
      </div>
    
      <%= yield %>
    </main>
  </body>
```

Is this even possible? If not, how would you implement this? I would also appreciate any feedback regarding the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few approaches to solving this problem, the simplest would be to add the ability to dynamically inject the message in the same `Share` controller.

Here is a full code example below.

##### 1. HTML

- This builds on what you had in your base template and also the HTML specific for the controller with a few changes.
- Firstly, we add a [`template`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) element to the inside the `#flash` element to house the client-side HTML content to copy for each message.
- We give this template a data attribute (can be anything) along with the actual content inside that houses the message text.
- For the controlled element, there is no need for your `data-share-target="trigger"` as you can always access the controlled element with `this.element` but it looks like you were not using it anyway.
- For your `button`, remember that adding [`type="button"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#notes) avoids the need to use `event.preventDefault` and it works better for accessibility.
- Remember to always include an accessible label for your buttons if you have a button that is an icon only. I have added `aria-label` but you could also add a span with [`sr-only` (looks like you are using Tailwind)](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screen-readers).

```html
<body>
  <div id="flash" class="w-full" aria-live="polite">
    <!-- ...flash.each do etc  -->
    <template data-template>
      <div><p data-value></p></div>
    </template>
  </div>
  <section>
    <h4>Share stuff</h4>
    <div
      data-controller="share"
      data-share-name-value="some-name"
      data-share-url-value="path/to/post/"
    >
      <button type="button" data-action="share#share" aria-label="share">
        Share
      </button>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

##### 2. Controller (JS)

- It looks like the way you were declaring your [static values](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/values) was incorrect, this should be an object syntax so that you can declare the type of the value for each one.
- Building on your controller code, we can add a new method `addMessage` that will find the element with the id `flash` and then template element inside. It will clone that element and then find where to put the message content. Then it will append this node into the flash container.
- Optional: Include a timeout on the message and remove it when you know the user has had time to see it.
- Once you have this `addMessage` method, you can use this method to show the 'clipboard updated' message and any errors if you need them to be shown to the user.
- Finally, the async/await feels like it is new and should be used but I think in this case it makes the code less readable. Using a simple `then` callback on the promise is more than sufficient for your use case.

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {
  static values = {
    messageTimeout: { default: 2.5 * 1000, type: Number },
    name: String,
    url: String,
  };

  addMessage(content, { type = "error" } = {}) {
    const flashContainer = document.getElementById("flash");

    if (!flashContainer) return;

    const template = flashContainer.querySelector("[data-template]");
    const node = template.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
    node.querySelector("[data-value]").innerText = content.message;

    flashContainer.append(node);

    // optional - add timeout to remove after 2.5 seconds
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      node.remove();
    }, this.messageTimeoutValue);
  }

  share() {
    const name = this.nameValue;
    const url = this.urlValue;

    const shareData = {
      name,
      text: "some cool text",
      title: "title here",
      url,
    };

    try {
      if (navigator.share) {
        navigator.share(shareData).catch((error) => this.handleError(error));
      } else {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(url);
        this.addMessage({ message: "copied to clipboard" }, { type: 'info' });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      this.handleError(error);
    }
  }
}
```

##### Alternative approach

Another way to do this would be to split out the flash message behaviour to a new controller. This would be useful if you expect other code to need to create messages dynamically.

Here is a reference implementation you could use for this.

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/main/client/src/controllers/MessagesController.ts (Wagtail, a CMS built on Django, has a similar global messages use case).

You could also use a Stimulus approach for the 'remove after a delay' part only, here is a reference implementation for the 'toast' style removal.

https://github.com/stimulus-components/stimulus-notification/blob/master/src/index.ts

Best to start simple and only add this separate controller behaviour only if you need it though.